# Javascript function not executing when another function is above it

Tags: javascript, html, function

So, the function "txtLoad()" will not execute while "txtFunc()" is being called by an onLoad function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<textarea id="Text" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
<script>
function txtFunc(){
    var q=1;
}
function txtLoad() {
    document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
onload=function(){
    txtLoad()
}
onload=function(){
    txtFunc()
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript engine says there is nothing wrong with the code inside the "script" element. Does anyone know why the function isn't executing?

Comment: You have an extra `}` before `txtLoad()`. Isn't it causing an error in the Javascript console? Did you bother to look?

Comment: Validate your JS. You have an extraneous `}` after the `txtfunc()` declaration.

Comment: Yes I did bother to look.

Comment: Chrome console say _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }_

Comment: Sorry, yes that extra } was an accident while writing, but that wasn't really the source.

Answer (score 3):

your second onload= replaced the function that calls txtLoad, if you want to run both:

```
onload = function () {
    txtLoad();
    txtFunc();
};
```

Also there seems to be extra "}" after the txtFunc.

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

How can two functions be defined to the onload. For eg:

```
var x  = 1
var x  = 2
```

What do you think the value of x is going to be? Obviously 2.

You are overwriting the onload. Its only going to execute the stuff which you assigned at last.

You could do this to achieve what you want.

```
onload = init()
function init() {
    textLoad();
    textFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply because the first onload was overwritten by the las onload.

Answer (score 0):

```
function txtFunc(){
    var q=1;

}
function txtLoad() {
    document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = "Hello";

}

onload=test();
function test()
{
    txtLoad();
    txtFunc();
}
```